# SQL Server 2012 installation error: Landing Page

Tags: sql-server, installation

After uninstalling SQL Server 2012 and 2008, then reinstalling, I get this error:

> Unhandled exception has occurred in your application...
>
> An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for userSettings/Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.LandingPage.Properties.Settings:

[image]

> See the end of this message for details on invoking just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
>
> ************** Exception Text **************
>
> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for userSettings/Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.LandingPage.Properties.Settings: Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (C:\Users\hy\AppData\Local\Microsoft_Corporation\LandingPage.exe_StrongName_ryspccglaxmt4nhllj5z3thycltsvyyx\10.0.0.0\user.config line 5) ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> File name: 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>
> at System.Configuration.TypeUtil.GetTypeWithReflectionPermission(IInternalConfigHost host, String typeString, Boolean throwOnError)
>   at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.Init(RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord, FactoryRecord factoryRecord)
>   at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.InitWithRestrictedPermissions(RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord, FactoryRecord factoryRecord)
>   at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.CreateSectionFactory(FactoryRecord factoryRecord)
>   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.FindAndEnsureFactoryRecord(String configKey, Boolean& isRootDeclaredHere)
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
>   To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
>   Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
>   To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.FindAndEnsureFactoryRecord(String configKey, Boolean& isRootDeclaredHere)
>   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
>   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
>   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
>   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
>   at System.Configuration.ClientSettingsStore.ReadSettings(String sectionName, Boolean isUserScoped)
>   at System.Configuration.LocalFileSettingsProvider.GetPropertyValues(SettingsContext context, SettingsPropertyCollection properties)
>   at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertiesFromProvider(SettingsProvider provider)
>   at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertyValueByName(String propertyName)
>   at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.get_Item(String propertyName)
>   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.GetPropertyValue(String propertyName)
>   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.get_Item(String propertyName)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.LandingPage.LandingPageForm.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Delete the

`C:\Users\hy\AppData\Local\Microsoft_Corporation\LandingPage.exe_StrongName_ryspccglaxmt4nhllj5z3thycltsvyyx\`

directory, and try again.

I believe the uninstall sometimes does not clean up the files completely.

Comment: The file name is contained in the error log, but I weren't see it

Comment: how can i go to this location in windows 10.

Comment: i am not getting this location how can i find it ??? please help me . i have not installing sql server 2012.

Comment: @JoyAcharya in W10 is exactly the same. You have to replace hy by your user name.

Answer (score 4):

Search in this folder: 
`C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Microsoft_Corporation`

There you will find files or folders like

- `LandingPage.exe`, 
  or
- `LandingPage.`

Delete all these folders.
Works for Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to find it if you search for `%localappdata%\Microsoft_Corporation%`

Answer (score 1):

Rename the `user.config` file located at

> C:\Users[USER_NAME]\AppData\Local\Microsoft_Corporation\LandingPage.exe_StrongName_ryspccglaxmt4nhllj5z3thycltsvyyx\10.0.0.0

to

> USER.CONFIG.BAK

Answer (score 0):

Delete this Folder `C:\Users\yourName\AppData\Local\Microsoft_Corporation\LandingPage.exe_StrongName_ryspccglaxmt4nhllj5z3thycltsvyyx\`

Answer (score 0):

Run the command: `rd /s /q %localappdata%\Microsoft_Corporation1as`